# How to get the name of next path when navigating

Tags: skmaps

I am developing an navigation android app that use Skobbler SDK. Currently, the advice received is totally voice data, but I would like to know the name of next path in the route. 
Could anyone tell me how can I get the name of the next path when navigating. For example, when I get the instruction is "turn left in 200 meters", how to know what is name of the next path after turn left.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2.3 version, by default the street name is not included in the audio advices - this is due to the fact that we use mp3 files for the audio and street names can not be handled this way.

In 2.4 you will have the possibility of using TextToSpeech as an alternative audio engine so you'll have the possibility of using street names.

What can you do in 2.3?

1. Handle the [didChangeNextStreetName](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/2.3.0/Protocols/SKNavigationDelegate.html#//api/name/routingService:didChangeNextStreetName:streetType:countryCode:) (iOS) callback - this should provide information you are looking for (on Android it's [onUpdateNavigationState](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.3.0/com/skobbler/ngx/navigation/SKNavigationListener.html#onUpdateNavigationState(com.skobbler.ngx.navigation.SKNavigationState)) and call in the SKNavigationState object the getNextAdviceNextStreetName method)
2. Modify the config file of the advices engine to include the name of the street in the advices (send an email to support for this information)

Comment: Thank you for your instruction. It resolve my problem.